# How to retrieve a list of all articles of Fogbugz-wiki that have a certain tag?

Tags: api, rest, tags, wiki, fogbugz

Via the `Fogbugz` REST API I try to get all articles with a certain tag. I wrote some code in `python` to get it but I got "zero" as result. Here is my code:
import requests
...
some code to log in
...

```
req_params={"cmd": "search", "token": self.token,"q":"tag:\"my_cool_tag\""}
response = requests.get(req_url, data=req_body, headers=req_header, params=req_params, verify=False)
print (response.text)
```

as response I got:
...cases count="0"...
Is there a way to get all articles with a certain tag in a list via REST-API and how I can achieve this?
I am using `FogBugz Version 8.8.49.0.`

Comment: Did my answer below help at all, or are you still struggling?

Answer (score 0):

Try the search with curl or directly in your web browser to check that it works, then see if you can debug your Python.

In a browser I can successfully query FogBugz Online with something like:

```
https://<domain>.fogbugz.com/api.asp?token=<token>&cmd=search&q=tag:%22<my_tag>%22
```

Although I entered quotes around my tag, the browser url encoded them to `%22`. Obviously `<domain>`, `<token>` and `<my_tag>` should be replaced with your own values.

Your basic parameters look OK, but I haven't used Python so am not sure whether escaping the quotes around the tag translates well to the GET request? Maybe try url encoding `"my_cool_tag"`.